# Windows 10 pairing with an Android peripheral

Tags: android, uwp, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

The pairing process on Windows 10 will not result in establishing a successful connection on Android when Android device plays the peripheral role. The pairing process which is directly handled by the OSs on both sides (regardless of which services you are advertising) is being failed during updating the connection parameters such as Interval, Latency, and Timeout.
It seems both sides are looking for different settings on the connection. We recently tried to simulate another peripheral device using the NRFconnect android app by advertising a battery service for example. The connection will be dropped immediately after failing on compromising on the connection parameter settings. See the attached log files for the NRFConnect words, announcing why the connection is being terminated when it works with Windows. Just for the record, there is no problem when we change the central with another Android device.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: What you need to reproduce this is just having a peripheral app. You may know for going further on Windows we first need to do the pairing first. NRFConnect developed by Nordic can be used on Android to make it as peripheral, i.e. for start advertising.